# azure mobile apps cordova minified errors when passing parameters within .where(clauseObj)

Tags: javascript, cordova, azure, plugins, parameters

The question is regarding the azure-mobile-apps-cordova-client-master.

The minified version of the javascript sdk does not work when passing parameters in the .where(param) or in any of the other ones. It gives the following error message:

> unsupported expression 'null'

After a lot of debugging, it looks like that there are certain expressions in the sdk MemberExpression, or ConstantExpression etc. that are used by the sdk to evaluate and build the query expressions. In the normal .js file, it works fine (like on the web page). However, when the app is compiled for the mobile device OR if I use the minified version in the web, those variables are shortened, and the query expression builder no longer works. The error occurs at line 6599

```js
/*       * Visit a node.       */        
Visitor.prototype.visit = function(node) {        
var element, _i, _len, _results;        
if (_.isArray(node)) {          
  _results = [];          
  for (_i = 0, _len = node.length; _i < _len; _i++) {            
    element = node[_i];            
    _results.push(this.visit(element));          
  }          
  return _results;        
  } else if (!(node != null ? node.type : void 0)) {          
    return node;        
  } 
  else if (!_.isFunction(this[node.type])) {          
    throw "Unsupported expression " + (this.getSource(node));        
  } else {          
    return this[node.type](node);        
  }      
};
```

Comment: @Jeff, Thank you for the formatting.

Comment: To confirm, were you starting your project with the document https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-cordova-how-to-use-client-library? Or you used https://github.com/Azure/azure-mobile-apps-js-client#use-the-sdk-as-an-npm-package to install the SDK? Could you tell us how to reproduce your issue? And what special key code snippet which rise your issue?